# How to make STATIC_URL work in external JS Files (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

I am trying to use STATIC_URL in external javascript file. I was expecting the result as it is working in template, but I found that it is not working in external Javascript file.

Please also tell me some work around to make STATIC_URL work in javascript file as it will make my project more manageable.

Also I am sending many ajax request and i want to have something like url template tag in my JS file.

Please let me know if you know solution of any of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a simple Django app for making Python / Django settings available in javascript.

https://github.com/incuna/django-settingsjs

It works in the same way by rendering the settings in a template but provides a mechanism for making multiple variables available in JavaScript using a view, urls and optionally signals.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem is to pass `STATIC_URL` to your JavaScript code at some point so that it also knows the value. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myJavaScript('{{ STATIC_URL }}');
</script>
```

Your JavaScript function `myJavaScript` can then use it in URLs and wherever it is needed.

Comment: There is no other go for this other than passing it through template